# Do not apply settings for non-modifiable popup windows

Tags: vimrc

I have the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
:set colorcolumn=81
```

This sets the background color of every window's 81st column to red.
I would like to disable this for "pop-up" windows like syntastic's error display window or jedi's docstring window. Since buffers similar to these are usually non-modifiable I thought I might be able to only active colorcolumn for modifiable buffers but I can not figure out how.

Comment: Should be no problem with an autocommand with event, oh,  `BufReadPost` probably. Have it check the newly opened buffer and set `colorcolumn` only when desired conditions exist.

Comment: See my edit, I get what you mean but I'm not sure on the details.

Comment: All right. Good job. Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding my solution as an answer, the following snippet solves my problem:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter * call SetColorColumn()

function! SetColorColumn()
    if &modifiable
        set colorcolumn=81
    else
        set colorcolumn&
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Can be shorter as: `autocmd BufwinEnter * let &l:colorcolumn = &modifiable ? 81 : 0` – probably also better to use `&l:` (which sets the local variable, like `setlocal`) instead of setting the global one.